# How to pass props and state down through multiple children?

Tags: reactjs

I have several React components put together in a chain that looks something like this:

Dashboard->CallScreen->CallControls->AddressingPopup

There is functionality that I want to use from the Dashboard component inside of AddressingPopup. I've tried passing props through all the children using {...this.props} which doesn't let me access the state it seems.
How can I pass EVERYTHING down the chain to AddressingPopup?

Comment: 'which doesn't let me access the state it seems' - could you explain more about this? You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to avoid prop chaining.

Comment: @RameshReddy There's a part of state in Dashboard that I want to use all the way down the chain in AddressingPopup , context seems like the way to  go.